# CSS margin and padding doesnt seem to work

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add margin and padding to my CSS code but it seems to overlap each other and doesn't work as required.

```
  #logodiv{
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #990000;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#signindiv{
    font-weight:bold;
    height:35px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #990000;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;

}

#signindiv img{
    position:relative;
    top:3px;
}

#topmenudiv{
    float:left;
    height:42px;
}

#topmenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right: 1px solid #990000;
}
```

Have been trying to rescale the here below but its not positioning the way i want it positioned.

```
#topmenudiv li{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:0.9em;
    border-right: 1px solid #990000;
    padding:0 15px 0 20px;
    height:25px;
    float:left;
}
#searchdiv{
    float:left;
    padding:5px 0 0 10px;
}

#searchdiv input{
    height:25px;
    border:none;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    background-image:url("images/magnify.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:15px 15px;
    background-position:right center;
}

.break{
    clear:both;
}

#newsbar{
    background-color: #990000;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    color:white;
 }
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="fixedwidth">
            <div id="logodiv">
                <img src="images/bbc-logo.png"  />
            </div>
            <div id="signindiv">
                <p><img src="images/signin.png"  />Sign In</p>
            </div>
            <div id="topmenudiv">
                <ul>
                    <li>News</li>
                    <li>Sports</li>
                    <li>Weather</li>
                    <li>iPlayer</li>
                    <li>TV</li>
                    <li>Radio</li>
                    <li>More...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="searchdiv">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div id="newsbar">
        <div class="fixedwidth"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok at the .topbar div the borders separating each #topmenudiv are over extending downwards but in real sense they should end directly where the border height is ending and plus there is a white space between the #newsbar id and the .topbar div. That is where my problem is.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? It would be easy to help.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what you are trying to do?

Comment: What exactly doesnt seem to work? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: How do you want your elements position? Which one where to put? This I don't get!

Comment: If possible could you share rough sketch for the header section. What you are looking for exactly. ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/